# How to find running server or client ip and its port in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I am setting up cluster of Apache Ingine servers, I am using below code,

```
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("10.154.8.208","10.154.8.121:3389","127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
```

If I run the Java code `n` times, `n` number of server starts, using one of the IP Address and its default/specific port present in the list of IP Addresses.

I want Java code to find on which IP and port servers started. Please help me in finding these values.

Below is the sample code I am using,

```
public class IgniteClientStaticIP {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();

ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("10.154.8.208","10.154.8.121:3389","127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();


cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);


cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);


Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

IgniteCompute igniteCompute = ignite.compute();
igniteCompute.broadcast(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"));

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need these addresses? Usually this is something that you don't need to know in Java code, since Ignite discovery SPI address can be used only by other Ignite nodes internally. You can find the address to which a node has attached in logs.

Answer (score 1):

As [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6708961/denis) suggests this is not something you would ordinarily need to do. However I have seen cases where it's necessary, including automating load balancer or firewall rules. So with that caveat...

You can get information about nodes using the `ClusterNode` class. Well, in this case `TcpDiscoveryNode`, which is a more specific version of `ClusterNode.` This is Scala but you should get the gist:

```
scala> ignite.cluster.nodes.asScala.flatMap { case x : TcpDiscoveryNode => Some(x.socketAddresses) case _ => None }
res5: Iterable[java.util.Collection[java.net.InetSocketAddress]] = ArrayBuffer([XX/192.168.1.89:47501, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0:47501, /127.0.0.1:47501], [XX/192.168.1.89:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500])
```